# Selenium extent report does not shows multibyte character properly, it is showing as ? mark

Tags: selenium

1. I tried old and latest version as well
2. Eclipse project configured for UTF-8
3. extent config xml file is having set to UTF-8

all above point is done but still not getting multibyte character

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  in configuration of Surefire plugin in pom.xml